# Extract queries from MS access 97

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-97

I am working on an application coded with **Microsoft access 97** the application is working so good but now I am migrating it to sql server but i need to extract queries in order to understand the content of the old database (**Ms access 97**) I am not able to find those queries ! and when I click excute query the error message is "Microsoft Jet could not find the object 'Requete1'  "

Comment: How are you trying to open the database/queries?

Comment: when I open the datbase file with ms access it displays all the tables and when click the queries section nothing appears

Comment: What version of Access are you opening it with? And by "nothing appears" do you mean: an empty resultset or nothing at all..

Comment: I am opning it with Ms access 97, I mean empty resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get access to the queries using the macros